# Probability that a random weight function on $K_n$ satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: probability, graph-theory

On a complete graph $K_n$, every edge is assigned a random real weight in $[0, 1]$. I am trying to calculate the probability that the weights satisfy the triangle inequality or even bounds on this probability. How about the discrete version where the weights are integers in $[0, k]$?

**EDIT**: the question was asked and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99813/probability-that-random-weights-on-k-n-satisfy-triangle-inequality).

Comment: For $n=3$ the probability is $\frac12$.  Empirically, for $n=4$ the probability seems to be between $0.141$ and $0.142$ so I doubt there is an easy expression for large $n$.

Comment: @Henry I arrived at the same results. I have been trying to even find the rate at which the probability approaches zero, but I am failing at that too..

Comment: Also posted on Mathoverflow now, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99813/probability-that-random-weights-on-k-n-satisfy-triangle-inequality